# Unity Shader Graph alpha has a blue red tint

Tags: unity-game-engine, graph, shader

Not sure why this is happening.
I have a fire texture I generate, and I mask it with a vertical gradient which I used to feed into the output alpha. That worked perfectly. No blue hue as it got higher nor red hue as it gets lower.

But I needed a texture under the fire. So I put one as an input and blended between the texture and the fire texture by putting in the old alpha fire thing but it turned the bottom red and the top blue.

Is there a better way to overlay textures? I have the blend set to overwrite.

I tried desaturating the alpha from purple to gray. I tried splitting it and using just the red channel.